# Control density of a volume in a more methodical way

Tags: volumetrics

I would like to have a volume mesh, let's say a sphere, that gets progressively more "misty"

[image]

Imagine the mesh being at very high desnity for the top hemisphere, then density becomes lower in the lower hemisphere to the point that it basically transitions to a gas. I want this to be possible to be added to any mesh and control where the lower density happens.
I have attempted many ways to achieve this, but controlling the density is not really possible in an arbitary way, only with 3D textures (noise or gradient).

Comment: Quite interesting ... would you mind to extend your description to be more specific what is your goal visually .... some references (it should be still image or anim) ... why procedural texture doesn't work for you ... Probably any dissolving / disintegration technique like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wm4rDDRcbDQ could work for you? Just instead of spark material you will use something volumetric.

Answer (score 4):

*Until you add more details (mentioned in my comment) ...*

One way to dissolve solid into a "gas" can be faked simply by **Plane** used at the same time as factor for

- *Boolean* modifier and
- *Canvas* of *Dynamic Paint*

*Boolean* operator will handle "disappearing" solid part. *Dynamic Paint* (with *Sphere* as a *Brush* and *Plane* as *Canvas*) will generate *Weight* (Vertex Group) as *Fluid Sim > Gas > Inflow*.

[image]

Added *Solidify* modifier to the Plane, to avoid glitches of *Boolean* modifier (even with *Exact* solver).

[image]

Previously I let emit smoke from Particle system (based on DP weight) , but it was somehow unstable for me (it is still included in the file, just disabled).

There can be more ways using just geometry nodes or Particle system, but in cost of less realistic "gas" dissolving.

Comment: Could you share the .blend you used?

Comment: very interesting approach!

Answer (score 3):

You can try *object coordinates* with multiple *Empties*.
Density/spread is controlled by: scaling empties, *ColorRamp*, *Math node > Multiply*

<sup>High, medium and low density areas</sup>
[image]

<sup>Combining three areas, each driven by a separate empty (click to enlarge)</sup>
[image]

Comment: I see, that's a great idea, I will try that out. I wish in the next version of blender we get collection input so that we could get texture coordinate from all the empties at once